# Re-parenting Trigger Incorrectly Re-parents all Children to a Single Parent

Tags: trigger, loop

I wrote the folloing re-parenting trigger to reparent Contacts with their parent Accounts, this is based on a unique identier (TFID). If I test each record one by one they all re-parent correctly, however, if I use Dataloader to load a large batch all of them get re-parented to the same parent Account (the parent of the last Contact record inserted).

```
trigger reParentContactsbyTFIDs on Contact (after insert) {

List<Contact> unParentedContacts = [SELECT id, recordTypeId FROM Contact WHERE recordTypeId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' AND id = :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];



    set<String> TFIDs = new set<String>();
    for(Contact cont : [SELECT id, TFID__c 
                     FROM Contact 
                     WHERE id 
                     IN :unParentedContacts]){

    TFIDs.add(cont.TFID__c);
    }


    set<String> parentAccounts = new set<String>();
    for(Account pacct : [SELECT id 
                     FROM Account 
                     WHERE TFID__c IN :TFIDs]){

    parentAccounts.add(pacct.id);
    }


    for(Contact cont : unParentedContacts) {
        for(String pacct : parentAccounts){
            cont.accountId = pacct;
    }}

    update unParentedContacts;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do this in a `before insert` trigger to avoid any need to do an update:

```
trigger reParentContactsbyTFIDs on Contact (before insert) {

    Id rtId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

    Set<String> tfids = new Set<String>();
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.RecordTypeId == rtId && c.TFID__c != null) tfids.add(c.TFID__c);
    }

    Map<String, Id> m = new Map<String, Id>();
    for (Account a : [select TFID__c, Id from Account Where TFID__c in :tfids]) {
        m.put(a.TFID__c, a.Id);
    }

    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.RecordTypeId == rtId && c.TFID__c != null) c.AccountId = m.get(c.TFID__c);
    }
}
```

The map in the middle section of this code ensures the right Account ID is assigned in the bulk case (assuming the TFID values are unique on Account.)

Comment: The Map collection worked perfectly. The before insert is much more effecient. Since its an insert, the TFID field will always be null. Smart Cookie.